# Cómo separar DIV de INPUTs?

Tags: html, css, web, diseño

Estoy cargando datos a una tabla dinámica desde unos campos de texto que tengo en un DIV.

El problema es que no logro hacer que la parte inferior del div no este tan pegado a los campos.

Así lo tengo:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="col-lg-11"
  style="border-radius:4px;margin:auto;border-style:dotted;border-width:1px;padding-bottom:10px;" >
  <div class="col-lg-1">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Codigo</label>
    <input name="campo1" id="campo1" type="text"
    class="form-control" required pattern="[0-9]+">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Servicio</label>
    <input name="campo2" id="campo2" type="text"
    class="form-control" readonly="readonly" minlength=5 maxlength="40"  required>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Largo</label>
    <input name="campo3" id="campo3" type="text"
      class="form-control" required pattern="[0-9]+">

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Ancho</label>
    <input name="campo4" id="campo4" type="text"
      class="form-control" required pattern="[0-9]+">

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Alto</label>
    <input name="campo5" id="campo5" type="text" class="form-control" required pattern="[0-9]+">
    <input type = "hidden" name = "campo6" id="campo6" value="un"/>
    <input type = "hidden" name = "campo7" id="campo7" value="10000"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Insertar</label> <br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="botonOk" >   OK   </button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Probaste agragandole la propiedad padding-bottom al div ?

Comment: podrías aplicarle margin-bottom a tus input
otra opción seria aplicarle padding: 10px; a tu div

Comment: Debes poner el código para que podamos ayudarte!

Comment: Ya lo edite, le agregue el código. La respuesta de Sacha me ayudo. Gracias y Saludos

Comment: No se deberían responder preguntas con esta calidad: [Enlace] (https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/840/qu%C3%A9-deber%C3%ADamos-hacer-a-las-preguntas-del-tipo-no-he-intentado-pero-quiero-resp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agrega padding-bottom: 10px al div que contiene  tu input

Comment: gracias por el apoyo pero preguntas que no muestran lo que han tratado o que errores concretos tienen en el código no se deberían responder hasta que el OP mejore su pregunta

Comment: Ya lo edite, le agregue el código, no lo puse de un principio por que no pense que fuera necesario para un DIV, por eso puse la imagen. Gracias @DeivGuerrero